# IBM Watson Text-to-speech API keeps throwing Error: 403 Forbidden

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-text-to-speech

I've been using the IBM Watson Text-to-speech API for quite a while now. The service credentials that was working until last night has been throwing an `{"code":403, "error": "Forbidden"}` since this morning.

I use the lite plan and London region I tried curl requests and it still doesn't work or given any further logs. I tried with a newly created pair of credentials, it's still throwing the same error. Any ideas?
Here's the curl request sample although the error persists in my original python app too:

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:{apikey}" --output hello_world.wav "{url}/v1/synthesize?accept=audio%2Fwav&amp;text=Hello%20world&amp;voice=en-US_AllisonVoice"
```

Comment: im guessing your api-key or your IP has been blacklisted somehow, contact IBM customer support.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add this as a comment, but I need to add pictures, so ...

IBM Cloud is switching off any services that have not been migrated to a resource group. The Watson services are one of the first batch affected.

If you see this icon [image]

next to your service instance then then you haven't yet migrated your service instance, and need to do so.

If you see this icon [image]
then you have migrated and there is something else going awry.