# How to know if an application is using Cloud Foundry?

Tags: .net, cloud-foundry, ibm-watson, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a .NET application that uses IBM Watson for sentiment analysis. I am new to this project and don't know the proper working of the IBM Watson. Recently, sentiment Analysis stopped working and we sent an email to IBM about it and they said that it might because we have not yet migrated it from Cloud Foundry to Resource Group.

I don't know whether we are using Cloud Foundary or not. How can I check it? 
People who have worked on this project before are currently not available and I am on my own now.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to migrate from Cloud Foundry, see [Migrating Watson services from Cloud Foundry](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=watson-migrate).

You can find out details about the service instance that you are using by clicking the service instance in your [Resource list](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources?groups=resource-instance) on IBM Cloud and looking at the credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By looking at the IBM cloud I was able to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Your project is most probably using the sentiment features of the Watson Natural Language Understanding service. Service documentation can be found here - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/natural-language-understanding?topic=natural-language-understanding-getting-started

If you are writing .net code then your link to the appropriate API Documentation is https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding/natural-language-understanding?code=dotnet-standard

To check if your service is still on cloud foundary or has been migrated then check the answer in this question - [IBM Watson Text-to-speech API keeps throwing Error: 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856201/ibm-watson-text-to-speech-api-keeps-throwing-error-403-forbidden/59895609#59895609)