# The old Watson Conversation API (21st Apr 2017 version) seems to have stopped working. Gives me the 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

My application was using the Watson Conversation API (21st Apr 2017 version) imported as a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>conversation</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I've checked the credentials (username and password) for correctness. However, it is still giving me the following error (I've replaced the actual conversation workspace id with the placeholder ACTUAL_WORKSPACE_ID in URLs):

Feb 12, 2020 6:14:40 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 401 Unauthorized https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/ACTUAL_WORKSPACE_ID/message?version=2017-04-21 (342ms, 37-byte body)
Feb 12, 2020 6:14:40 PM com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService processServiceCall
SEVERE: POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/ACTUAL_WORKSPACE_ID/message?version=2017-04-21, status: 401, error: Unauthorized
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. Tip: Did you set the Endpoint?
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:410)

I observed that the newer version of APIs is available and the IAM & Resource groups have been introduced in the IBM Cloud. Is this issue a result of these changes?
Can we not use the older API any more?

Comment: That v1 API is still available: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1 Please format your question. Are you on a supported API V1 version (date)?

Comment: Actually, I've already mentioned that I am using the following API: https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1 (version 2017-04-21). However, I am not aware of whether this API is still supported and I also didn't find anything on the internet related to this.

Comment: For links to info about migrating, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60039767/5494819

Answer (score 1):

IBM Cloud is switching off any services that have not been migrated to a resource group. The Watson services were part of the first batch affected. You will need to migrate your instance to IAM, then use the generated IAM key for authentication.