# Watson NLU suddenly began returning {"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Our access to the api that has run for years suddenly stopped working and returns {"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}
There is no issue with signing into the account, charges or resource usage.
The only previous interruptions were when IBM purchased the original vendor and again when IBM changed some access requirements.
The application is .NET C# and the api returns title, author, and text from urls.
How can we find the cause of the interruption?
Thanks

Comment: Contact IBM. If you're paying for the service they should provide support. They'll be able to see the server side logs for the request.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [The old Watson Conversation API (21st Apr 2017 version) seems to have stopped working. Gives me the 401 Unauthorized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189034/the-old-watson-conversation-api-21st-apr-2017-version-seems-to-have-stopped-wo/60204832#60204832) and [How to know if an application is using Cloud Foundry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59961328/how-to-know-if-an-application-is-using-cloud-foundry/60039767#60039767)

The answer is the same :

IBM Cloud is switching off any services that have not been migrated to a resource group. The Watson services were part of the first batch affected. You will need to migrate your instance to IAM, then use the generated IAM key for authentication.

If you need to migrate from Cloud Foundry, see [Migrating Watson services from Cloud Foundry](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/natural-language-understanding?topic=watson-migrate).

You can find out details about the service instance that you are using by clicking the service instance in your [Resource list](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources?groups=resource-instance) on IBM Cloud and looking at the credentials.